# Reduces VS Code terminal spaces between letters

Tags: visual-studio-code

While i compiling the project in my laptop(mac) the terminal text spaces suddenly becomes bigger. I want to reduce the terminal space in the vs code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings in the left bottom in the settings and search terminal space the select unicode version as 6
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will encounter this spacing problem after setting up a custom font as:

> "editor.fontFamily": "'Ubuntu', 'monospace', monospace, 'Droid Sans Fallback'"

Comment: Is that setup for the editor or terminal?

Comment: It's placed in settings.json what affects terminal as well. Now i see that setting this triggers a notification that the terminal only supports monospace fonts with a button to set a mono. It appears to be the reason.